# How to add sub collection to a document in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

There is no documentation about how add sub collection in a document in Firestore, so how to add a sub collection by using a web app?

I tried this but it didn't work:

[image: Image of code (please replace with text)]

How can I add a sub collection in apps by using code? Is there any way to do it or it will be better to use Firebase real time database?
If so, please let me know how to do it in Firebase as well.

I want to add it like this:

[image: Image of desired result]

I did this:

[image: Another image of code (please replace with text)]

But I am getting an this error:

[image: Image of error message (please replace with text)]

Comment: The solution goes: Get the interested document (doc) and then:  doc.ref.collection('Collection_Name').add('Object_to_be_added')
It is advisable to include a then/catch after the promise.

Comment: OP can you please put code blocks into your question, and not images of code?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Your code should work if you change `.set` to `.add`.  Cloud Firestore will then issue a new ID for that document.  If you want to specify the document ID, then you'll need to do this...

### Set a book with a given ID

```
db.collection('users').doc(this.username).collection('booksList').doc(myBookId).set({
  password: this.password,
  name: this.name,
  rollno: this.rollno
})
```

This page details how to [Add data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

### Add a book

```
db.collection('users').doc(this.username).collection('booksList').add({
  password: this.password,
  name: this.name,
  rollno: this.rollno
})
```