# Storing nested collections in Firestore using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a simple chat application using Firebase and Firestore. The pseudo-schema I have in my mind looks like this:

```
• threads: collection
  |
  +---- • friend_id: str
        • last_messaged: timestamp
        • messages: collection
          |
          +---- • sender_id: str
                • text: str
                • timestamp: timestamp
```

Now, lets say my friend with an id of `420` messages me for the first time. I would want to store this data by creating a new thread. Lets say I do this using the following command:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
var db = admin.firestore();

var thread_id = '212';
var message_id = '3498213712';

db.collection('threads').add({
    id: thread_id,
    friend_id: '420',
    last_messaged: 1557862539,
    messages: [
        {
            id: message_id,
            sender_id: '420',
            text: 'Hello',
            timestamp: 1557862539
        }
    ]
})
```

Is this the right way to do things? Would a collection called `messages` be automatically created since I'm sending a JSON object in that field? If not, how can I do this the right way?

**EDIT**: Perhaps I was not clear enough earlier. I want `messages` to be a `sub-collection`. Right now, it is an array, according to a comment below.

**EDIT2**: Both `threads` id and `messages` are not random. Update the code to reflect that.

**NOT DUPLICATE**: Not a duplicate of the question linked in the comments because that question is for Java and the Android SDK, while this one is for Javascript.

Comment: That will create an array field on the thread document.

Comment: @Herohtar - Would you please write an answer explaining how?

Comment: What's wrong with your proposed solution?  Is something not working the way you expect?

Comment: @DougStevenson I specifically mentioned in the schema that `messages` have to be a collection. The code that I wrote creates an array field according to Herothar's comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add subcollection to a document in Firebase Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514419/how-to-add-subcollection-to-a-document-in-firebase-cloud-firestore)

Comment: @DougStevenson Everything is not working fine, because as I keep repeating, I want `messages` to be a collection. Right now, it is an array. I apologize if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: You've called your collection "threads" in your code.  Are you saying you want "messages" to be subcollection under a document in "threads"?

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, sorry I was not aware of the sub-collection terminology.

Comment: You will have to decide what you want your document ID to be for the document in the "messages" subcollection.  Do you have a document ID in mind, or do you want a random ID?  Please be specific about what you intend the final result to be.

Comment: @DougStevenson - Not random. Updated the code to reflect that, but I'm pretty sure the id needs to be set some other way, but hopefully, the idea is clear now.

Comment: Sorry, didn't look closely enough at the question. Try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873465/how-to-add-sub-collection-to-a-document-in-firestore). Although the other one is for Java, the format of the document/collection syntax is very similar so it's a good reference anyway.

Comment: You should know that your first document added is getting a random id.  This is what `add()` does.  Is that also what you wanted, given that you also have a specific thread id?  There is a big difference between the formal document ID recognized by Firestore, and a field called "id".  They are not the same.

Comment: @DougStevenson As I mentioned in the question, not random. Clearly I made an error in my code in the question, hence the existence of this question.  The `thread_id` and `message_id` need to be the formal document IDs, but I don't know how to set them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be building a reference to the document, then creating its contents using `set()` on that reference instead of `add()` (since add always creates a new random document id).  This is detailed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data), which I strongly recommend studuing in order to understand how Firestore works.  You will use that information a lot.

To create a document with a known ID (in the variable `thread_id`) in a top level document:

```
db.collection('threads').doc(thread_id).set({
    friend_id: '420',
    last_messaged: 1557862539
})
```

To create a document with a known ID in a subcollection, it's exactly the same, except you have to put the name of the subcollection in the path of the document reference:

```
db.collection('threads').doc(thread_id).collection('messages').doc(message_id).set({
    sender_id: '420',
    text: 'Hello',
    timestamp: 1557862539
})
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to make the whole process atomic?

Comment: Read about batched writes. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions