# how to add sub collection to a document in firestore? (Updated for for web v 9)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a similar question to [how to add sub collection to a document in firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873465/how-to-add-sub-collection-to-a-document-in-firestore), but I am using web version 9. The firebase documentation reads values in a subcollection, but I am trying to add a document to a subcollection.

I just need an example on how to add a document using web version 9 because I can not find one.